# PostgresSQL query returns None in Python (Works on PgAdmin)

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following query:

```
def is_paying_user(user_id: int) -> bool:
    with Database() as cursor:
        res = cursor.execute(f"""SELECT is_paying FROM public."Users" WHERE user_id = {user_id}""")
        return res.fetchone()
```

user_id is an integer.

`Database` is a context manager defined as:

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS,
                                           host=LOCALHOST, port=DB_PORT)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.connection.cursor()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()
```

And I am getting the following error when calling `is_paying_user`:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
```

When I grab the integer value and run the same query on PgAdmin it succeeds.

I also tried a few variations of the same query (got same error):

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT trackables_amount FROM public."Users" WHERE user_id = %s""", (user_id,))

cursor.execute("""SELECT trackables_amount FROM public."Users" WHERE user_id = %s""", user_id)
```

Comment: execute method returns None, you should return cursor.fetchone() instead

Comment: Word to the wise read this [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) esp: "**Warning Never, never, NEVER**  use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `cursor.execute` [is undefined](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#id20); you want to call `.fetchall` (or `.fetchone`) [on the cursor object](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#fetchone)!